# Creating virtual url in Opencart that uses original folders

Tags: opencart

I have been trying to make a mini opencart as per vendor. I have changed the .htaccess file so that whenever it encounters url ending with vendor/vendor_name it redirects to the index.php page of opencart, but then in the opencart if any url is called then it is redirected to the original opencart url i.e opencart/index.php. Changing url wont work because then the path for files and folder also gets changed. Can someone please help me out here so that i can create a virtual url such that it still uses opencart's files and folders?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

place in .htaccess before the redirection line ...
maybe it would works for you ...

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it does not work.
I think there is some issue in routing after the index page.